# Error al conectar con la base de datos

Tags: php, mysql, mariadb

Estoy trabajando con un servidor Debian en cual tengo una base de datos con MariaDB, no esta instalado PHPMyAdmin.

Desde la terminal al ejecutar `show databases;` me da el siguiente resultado:

```
+---------------------+
| Databases           |
+---------------------+
| information_schema  |
| pruebas             |
| mysql               |
| performance_schema  |
+---------------------+
```

Ingreso a pruebas; `use pruebas;` y me muestra la tabla usuario:

```
+---------------------+
| ID | nombre | pass  |
+---------------------+
| 1  | mario  | 12345 |
| 2  | ana    | 23456 |
| 3  | luis   | 34567 |
| 4  | juan   | 45678 |
+---------------------+
```

Hasta ahí todo funciona bien, pero cuando hago el archivo de conexión tengo este error:

> Connection failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1698] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'

conexion.php

```
<?php

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "prueba1234";

try {
  $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=longa", $username, $password);
  $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  echo "Connected successfully";
} catch(PDOException $e) {
  echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}

?>
```

Nota: al configurar el usuario y la contraseña de la base de datos cree el usuario `pruebaroot` y la contraseña `prueba1234`, si cambio el usuario `root` por `pruebaroot` el error es este:

> Connection failed: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'pruebaroot'@'localhost' (using password: YES)

Agradezco la ayuda de antemano.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El primer error que indicas  SQLSTATE[HY000] [1698] se debe a que la BBDD no permite el acceso al  usuario de root  sin permisos de sudo.

En este enlace  hay una [resolucion al error 1698](https://gist.github.com/manhlinhng/b43d05612c1a901d04566c1fbe1f292c)

En cuanto al segundo error (SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied)  la base de datos te esta denegando el acceso por fallo de las credenciales , revisa que el usuario y la pass sean  correctas.

Antes de utilizar el usuario de root es recomendable que trate de acceder con pruebasroot resolviendo los problemas de acceso.

Puede ejecutar `mysql -u pruebaroot -p` y tratar de logarse con ese usaurio desde la consola.

Una ultima cosa , estas intentando conectarte a un base que no exite en tu base de datos:

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=longa", $username, $password);
```

Si esta tratando de conectarse a la base de pruebas deberia verse asi:

```
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=pruebas", $username, $password);
```